# React function working on componentDidMount but not onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick

if I change my code from this

```
  componentDidMount(){
    let interval = setInterval(this.timer, 1000);
    this.setState({ secondsRemaining: this.state.secondsRemaining })
    this.setState({ interval: interval });
  };
```

to this:

```
  startTime(){
    let interval = setInterval(this.timer, 1000);
    this.setState({ secondsRemaining: this.state.secondsRemaining })
    this.setState({ interval: interval });
  };

<p><input type="submit" value="Start Timer!" onClick={this.startTimer}/></p>
```

I can get an error saying `Cannot read property 'timer' of null` pointing to the `let interval` line

Why would I get this? (binding error?)

I thought this next part would solve that:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      secondsRemaining: 10
    };
    this.timer = this.timer.bind(this);
  }
```

Maybe some stuff has not mounted? I cant work out why it works onMount but not onClick

Comment: You're using `startTimer` and `startTime`?

Comment: bind also 'this' to setInterval...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have to change `this.timer = this.timer.bind(this);` to `this.startTimer = this.startTimer.bind(this);` in your constructor function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use arrow function for binding:

`JSX`

```
<p><input type="submit" value="Start Timer!" onClick={() => this.startTimer.bind(this)}/></p>
```

Comment: I wanted to accept this one as I have used that before but it did not work for some reason? what do i need in the constructor?

Comment: My bad arrow function is not necessary in this case, just:

Comment: onClick={this.startTimer.bind(this)} - just bind the context :)